# How can I ignore select option

Tags: html, html-select

I have several selects on my page with names `sport` and `processed`. When I select in first select `Soccer` and in second - `true` I have this request to server: `http://localhost/?sport=1&processed=true`.

**My question is:**

1) is it possible to ignore `All` options in both selects. So, when I select `All` in both or one selects the select value is ignored in request.

For example:

```
| Sport  | Processed | request                                  |
|--------|-----------|------------------------------------------|
| All    | All       | http://localhost/                        |
| Soccer | All       | http://localhost/?sport=1                |
| All    | yes       | http://localhost/?processed=true         |
| Soccer | yes       | http://localhost/?sport=1&processed=true |
```

2) is it possible to use only HTML and don't use JavaScript?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost" method="get">
            <p>
                <select name="sport" title="Sport">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="1">Soccer</option>
                    <option value="2">Tennis</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="processed" title="Processed">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="true">yes</option>
                    <option value="false">no</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done without javascript. A javascript solution might be to remove or disable the select tag from form at the time of submit if the selected value is an empty string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $(':submit').click(function(){
              $('select').each(function(){
                  if ( $(this).val() == '' )
                  {
                      $(this).remove(); // or $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                  }
              });
         });
    });
</script>
```